# Why $-1 \leq\frac{\langle A,B\rangle}{||A||\, ||B||}\leq1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm reading Apostol's Calculus.

It says that due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality written as:

$$|\langle A,B\rangle|\leq ||A||\, ||B||$$

Then

$$-1\leq\frac{\langle A,B\rangle}{||A||\, ||B||}\leq 1$$

I am a bit confused at this. I did the following to check that if:

$$A=(a_1,a_2,a_2) \quad B=(b_1, b_2, b_3)$$

Then:

$$\frac{a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2}}$$

But from here, I can only expand the square roots. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to check the [proof of the CS inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality#Proof)?

Comment: If you believe "vector calc" results that $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{u}=|\vec{v}|\cdot|\vec{u}|\cos(\theta)$ then you only have to put absolute values on things and note that $|\cos(\theta)|\leq 1$.  This is re-written as $\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u}}{|\vec{v}|\cdot|\vec{u}|}=\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Wait, which are you trying to prove? The first inequality, or figuring out why Cauchy-Schwarz implies the second inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if we accept the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (a proof can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof)):

$$|\langle A, B\rangle| \leq \|A\|\|B\| \iff -\|A\|\|B\|\leq \langle A, B\rangle \leq \|A\|\|B\|$$

Therefore dividing through by $\|A\|\|B\|$, we get:

$$-1\leq \frac{\langle A, B\rangle}{\|A\|\|B\|}\leq 1$$

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$|\langle A,B\rangle|\leq ||A||\, ||B|| \iff -||A||\, ||B|| \le \langle A,B\rangle\leq ||A||\, ||B|| $$

Answer (score 2):

You arrived at a point where the inequality is equivalent to
$$ (a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3)^2 \leq (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)$$
You can see that this is true by taking a look at [Lagrange's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Another way to see this is to look at the discriminant of the following second degree polynomial:

$$ p(x)= (a_1x+b_1)^2+(a_2x+b_2)^2+(a_3x+b_3)^2 $$
Since $p(x) \geq 0$ for every $x$, it follows that the discriminant is non-positive. That is exactly the desired inequality. Of course, all arguments work for $n$ terms instead of $3$.